# How to overcome dropdown menu on page content in tailwindcss?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css, solid-js

I created a dropdown menu using `Tailwindcss` in a `solid-js` application. The menu works well but it is displayed in the background of the screen content which causes it to be hidden by it. I would like the menu to display on the screen content than to display in the background. Here is my menu code:

```
<div className="fixed md:w-1/4 xl:w-1/5 pb-20 pt-4 left-0 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow border-r dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-white px-2 hover:overflow-y-auto body-scrollbar">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-2xl">{props.title}</h2>
       <ul className="mt-4 flex flex-col space-y-2">
        <For each={props.links}>
                {(item) => (
                  <li>
                     <NavLink
              href={item.href}
              className="flex items-center justify-between  py-2 px-2 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
              end={item.end}
              activeClass="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700"
            >
              <div className="flex items-center space-x-3">
                <div className="flex place-items-center p-2 bg-blue-500 rounded-full text-white text-xl">
                  {item.icon()}
                </div>
                <p>{item.name}</p>
              </div>
            </NavLink>
                </li>
              )}
        </For>
   { /*</select>*/}
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like part of this code was copied from a react or react-like project. While I have my doubts that `NavLink` is going to work as expected, your issue is that you're using `className` instead of `class` in some of your elements.